# Firefox duplcate library entries

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When I open my Firefox bookmarks library, I see two duplicates of the `All bookmarks` group, along with duplicates of the `History`,`Downloads`, and `Tags` items. The duplicates mirror the actual entries, and cannot be removed. The issue also occurs in Firefox safe mode. What is causing this? How can I fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: Removing them is not an active choice in the right click menu.

Comment: Ah, well there is always the nuclear option.  Backup you bookmarks, delete the places database and restore.